# Youtube's iframe embeds cover up html elements

Tags: html, wordpress, youtube

i've been working on a toolbar at the top of my sample website:

http://theplagueround.com/dev/

but it gets hidden behind any youtube video content.  i've seen a post or two about adding parameters to the  tag, but youtube is also using iframes now so that doesn't apply.

Comment: checked the z-index?
Place a div a huge zindex on it and see if it hides it.
If no.. try add another iframe to the same divwith another z-index.

One of these should do the trick but imo check carefully what is causing the problem.

What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a Youtube video appear behind your toolbar, you should add the parameter wmode=transparent to the end of the URL.

So change this:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H1Opn4DS88k" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to this:

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H1Opn4DS88k?wmode=transparent"     
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

More here:

- http://www.brandondawson.org/web-design/new-youtube-iframe-embed-code-wmodetransparent

If you don't want to hardcode the HTML into your posts, you should use a plugin like the one provided by @Tubal Martin. This has the advantage that if Youtube update their embed code in the future, you should only need to upgrade the plugin to the latest version.

Comment: thanks... wmode solves it.  i don't like hardcoding it, but this project has been going on forever and this is the fastest for right now.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try my plugin for Youtube (4000+ downloads so far): [Youtube shortcode](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-shortcode/)

No design issues have been reported.

Comment: looks like a great plugin! i needed to be able to insert the embed code into my theme options though.