# Dropdown behind youtube-video

Tags: jquery, menu, youtube, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a project, but I can't seem to get my dropdown-menu to appear in front of the embeded YoutTube-clip showing on my page in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Any solutions how to fix that?

See the problem here: http://www.klinikken-klintevej.dk.php5-21.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/Videobank/Fysioterapi/Honesty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube's iframe embeds cover up html elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093565/youtubes-iframe-embeds-cover-up-html-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Description

It is not possible to have a element over a youtube video which is on your page using the embed tag.

There is a trick with a `iframe` and `wmode=transparent` instead of the embed tag you may want to check out.

#### More Information

- [Float a div over a YouTube](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/float-div-youtube-iframe/)
- [Youtube's iframe embeds cover up html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093565/youtubes-iframe-embeds-cover-up-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the wmode of the video to opaque or transparent.
[this should give you more information about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue)